# AngularJS, using a promise within a service

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-service, angular-promise

I have one of those "really fat controller" controllers from an MVP of a project, that I'd like to refactor into more modular and compartmentalised code.

At present I have a function in my controller which:

1. Make an `$HTTP` call to an API
2. Processes the returned data with a `for` loop and a `switch` statement
3. Saves it to scope

I'd like to move this to a service. So far I have this:

```
angular.module('myApp.services', [])
.service('apiService', ['$http', 'webapiBase', function($http, webapiBase) {
  this.getData = function(){
    $http.get(webapiBase + '/api/getData').then(function(res){
      var obj = res.data;
      // Processing stuff
      return obj;
    }, function(err){
      return false;
    })
  }
}]);
```

In my controller, I need to run a callback when this service returns its data, like:

```
// In my Service:
this.getData = function(cb){
    $http.get(webapiBase + '/api/getData').then(function(res){
       var obj = res.data; 
       cb(obj);
    }, function(err){
       cb(false);
    })
  }

// In my controller
apiService.getData(function(data){
    $scope.data = data;
    // Do other stuff here
})
```

But this feels a bit weird/non-'Angular'.

Is there a more "Angular" way to achieve this, perhaps while using `$q`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to make a small modification to your service

```
  this.getData = function(){
    return $http.get(webapiBase + '/api/getData').then(function(res){
      // Processing stuff
      return object;
    }, function(err){
      return false;
    })
  }
```

Return the promise object of `$http.get` directly. Then in your controller

```
apiService.getData().then(function(data){
    $scope.data = data;
    // Do other stuff here
})
```

### Edit

If you really don't want to reuse the promise object created by `$http`, you can create your own real quick.

```
this.getData = function() {
    var deferred = $q.defer();

    $http.get(webapiBase + '/api/getData').then(function(res){
      // Processing stuff
      deferred.resolve(object);
    }, function(err){
      deferred.reject('error');
    });

    return deferred.promise;
}
```

Comment: A little confused - returning the $http.get function as a whole somehow lets me access a `then()` when I call `apiService.getData()`?

Comment: @Jascination yes, the reason you can execute `then` against $http.get() is `get()` will return a promise object. You can create your own using `$q` but personally I suggest to re-use the promise obj.

Comment: I see. So the `return` in `return object` is returning to the promise set by `$http`?

Comment: Yes, when you invoke `then(function x() {})` against `$http.get`, function x will be registered in the promise object internally. Once the request is finished and returns an object, the promise object will pass the result to function x.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `$q` to achieve what you're looking for.

```
// Your service
angular.module('myApp.services', [])
.service('apiService', ['$http', 'webapiBase', function($http, webapiBase) {
  this.getData = function() {
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    $http.get(webapiBase + '/api/getData').then(
        function (res) {
            // Do something with res.data
            deferred.resolve(res.data);
        },
        function(res){
            deferred.reject();
        }
    );
    return deferred.promise;
  }
}]);
```

Then consume the `$q` promise in your controller and respond to it:

```
// Your controller
apiService.getData().then(function(data) {
    $scope.data = data;
    // Do other stuff here
});
```

That's the Angular-way, using promises with `$q`.